# Custom ServerGate Task - "Agent.JobStatus" Does not Resolve

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am creating a new Azure DevOps custom task that will RUN ON "ServerGate". I have setup my HttpExecution for this task, and intend to use it for PRE and POST Deployment Approval Gate. When this executes for a Post Deployment Approval Gate, I would like to send the status of the job (i.e. Succeeded, Failed, etc) to my API. I thought I could just use "Agent.JobStatus" variable, but this is not resolving in the ServerGate.

Is there another variable I should use to get access to the status of the current stage (i.e. success?)?

Details on variables for Agent.JobStatus: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic

Details on authoring server gates I have been following: https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/servertaskauthoring.md

Example of my ServerGate:

```
"execution": {
    "HttpRequest": {
      "Execute": {
        "EndpointId":"",
        "EndpointUrl": "https://my-gate.com/ready",
        "Method": "POST",
        "Body": "{\"status\":\"$(Agent.JobStatus)\", \"name\":\"$(Release.ReleaseName)\"}",
        "Headers":"{\n\"Content-Type\":\"application/json\"\n}",
        "WaitForCompletion":"false",
        "Expression": "eq(root['approved'], 'true')"
      }
    }
  }
```

When this resolves in the output, the status just shows as: "$(Agent.JobStatus)".... while I am able to resolve the "name" into the actual name of the release definition in execution.

I expected to receive the proper status resolving on POST deployment gates to be "Successful", etc as indicated in the documentation noted above.

Answer (score 0):

I created a custom task to test this issue. I can reproduce the issue, even I used AGENT_JOBSTATUS instead. This job run on server or ServerGate, it  can be used in only an agentless job,  a server job does not require an agent or any target computers, so  the variable [Agent.JobStatus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) could not be referenced in agentless job. You may try to use [Service Endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) to post the agent job status to external service.

Comment: Thanks for confirming. I was hoping there might be an alternative to gather the status from the ServerGate directly. Sounds like I might not have much of a choice. I'll probably pass the ReleaseId through to the external service, which in turn can all back through the API to ask for the status of the job.

Comment: You can use this REST API(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/releases/get%20release?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0) to get the release informations. The response includes multiple status, such as ReleaseStatus and the release task status.

Comment: Yep that is the backup plan. I had hoped there was a status in the ServerGate, as it seems on a PostDeployment server gate this may be the #1 piece of information you'd want to know! Thanks for your help.